# Hausdorff measure and the volume form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

There are two tools, generalizing a concept of a volume to the case of submanifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$, namely the Hausdorff measure $H^k$ and the volume form. The question is how to show that if $M$ is an orientable  $k$-submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a volume form $dV$ then
$$
  \int\limits_{M} f(x) dV = \int\limits_{M} f(x) H^k(dx)
$$
if the integrals exist.

P.S. Maybe the question is too silly for MathOverflow and more suitable for Mathematics Stack Exchange, but I have 2 reasons to post it here:

1. In books on geometric integration theory (Krantz, Parks; Federer) I failed to find an answer.
2. I've already posted the question on Mathematics Stack Exchange and on one more forum, but I didn't receive any response.

Comment: It's not a silly question, but have you tried to work it out yourself for a smooth manifold using just the definitions and maybe the implicit function theorem?

Comment: Yes, in the case of $n=3$, $k=2$ it is the theorem about equality of the surface integrals of first and second kinds and there is no problem. In the case of arbitrary $n$ and $k$ I can manipulate with the integral on the left and I can receive some different representations of this integral (using local coordinates), but I don't know how to reduce the integral on the right to some suitable form.

Comment:  You have to use the area formula in Federer.

Comment: This is one of the folklore results that is well known and hard to find. It follows from Federer's area formula, but Federer's theorem is a way to difficult for this fact. The right proof has been sketched below by Anton Petrunin. Unfortunately it is not easy to find this argument in the literature.

Comment: The referenced [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107099/volume-form-and-hausdorff-measure) (to which the OP gave an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108442) four days later, without mentioning that it had been answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/87933)).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess you know that it is true in $\mathbb R^k$.

Without loss of generality we can assume that $f\ge 0$.
Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and cover your manifold by $(1\mp\varepsilon)$-Lipschitz charts.
Break your integrals into pieces using subordinate partition of unity and put these pieces back together.
Since in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ you have equality, you will get
$$
\int\limits_{M} f(x)\cdot dV\ \  \lessgtr\ \ (1\pm \varepsilon)^k\cdot\int\limits_{M} f(x)\cdot H^k(dx)
$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary your statement follows.