# Equality of Hausdorff measure and Lebesgue measure on manifolds (reference)

Tags: reference-request, smooth-manifolds, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Let  $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an $n$-dimensional $C^1$ submanifold (connected). We have two metric functions on $\mathcal{M}$:

- The Euclidean distance inherited from $\mathbb{R}^N$.
- The intrinsic Riemannian distance $d_\mathcal{M}(p,q)$ coming from the inherited inner product from $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Equivalently, $d_\mathcal{M}(p,q)$ is the infinum of lengths (in $\mathbb{R}^N$) of curves that join $p$ to $q$.)

Denote the corresponding $n$-dimesnional Hausdorff measures on $\mathcal{M}$ by $H^n$ and $H^n_\mathcal{M}$, respectively. It is well known that both measures coincide with the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ that is defined via integration of Jacobians of local parameterizations. Clearly, that follows from the area fomula in geometric measure theory. However, the result is simple and a sketch of the proof is given in https://mathoverflow.net/a/87933/121665. However, I would like to quote this result so my question is:

> **Question:** *What is the reference for the elementary proof of the
> fact that $H^n=H^n_\mathcal{M}=\mu$?*

There must be a textbook in measure theory or advanced calculus with a proof of this fact, but I am not aware of any such reference. Again, I would prefer to avoid quoting books on geometric measure theory like Federer, Evans & Gariepy or Krantz & Parks.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the point of asking for a reference of an elementary proof—so the worry is not the difficulty of understanding it—but rejecting a MathOverflow reference—so the worry is not the difficulty of accessing it—and geometric measure theory textbooks—so the worry is not whether the reference "looks authoritative"?

Comment: @LSpice I do not see your point. The idea is elementary, but if you want to write details formally, it is not. If you want to expose an non experienced reader to this problem, they would not know how to do it. The reason why it is so difficult to find a proof in standard textbooks is that, after all it is not so easy. Reference to MathOverflow is good, but only partially. Proofs are supposed to be valid forever. What is the post is deleted in 5 years from now?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz, I can understand wanting a reference to a proof in a more durable format than a notionally ephemeral website (although it is certainly possible, and perhaps even likely in the lifespan of MO, for textbooks to be or become so inaccessible that they might as well not exist), but then why forbid a reference to a particular kind of textbook?  (As to 'elementary', that was @‍BehnamEsmayli's characterisation, not mine.)

Comment: @LSpice  I still do not get your point. The proofs in the books mentioned by OP are not elementary at all. The point is that you do not need the general form of the area formula to prove this fact. I still believe that if possible, mathematics should be presented in a way that is accessible to a rather general audience of mathematical community. Otherwise we follow Fejer's rule: *everybody writes and nobody reads*.

Comment: There are proofs in the "Book Measure theory and Integration" by Taylor. Namely Propositions 12.6 and 12.7.